# Why Angular drag and drop cdk doesn't work?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I am developing an Angular (v7.3.8) application and I need to implement a drag-and-drop horizontal list inside a specific page of my app, named 'test.page'.
So I've used the new feature of Angular v7 cdk drag-and-drop, following this documentation:

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples

In my app.module.ts I have

```
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import ......

@NgModule({
    ....
    imports: [..., DragDropModule ],
    ... })
```

In my test.page.html I have:

```
<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
   <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let answer of answers" cdkDrag>{{answer}}</div>
</div>
```

And in my test.page.ts I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import ....

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.page.css'],
})
export class TestPage implements OnInit {
    answers = [ ....... ];

    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        moveItemInArray(this.answers, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }

    .....
    }
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work for me (the items of the list don't move using drag-and-drop), and I don't uderstand why.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: The code shown here looks fine. Consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to get more help.

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I installed the angular drag-and-drop cdk, I receveid these warnings:

npm WARN @ionic/pro@2.0.4 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-ionic@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/animations@7.2.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cdk@7.3.7
+ @angular/animations@7.2.14
+ @angular/material@7.3.7
updated 3 packages and audited 53275 packages in 72.436s


can this be the reason why that code doesn't work in my app? If yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: I guess it could be a problem. Try to do a clean install, remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and execute `npm install`. Otherwise open a new question regarding your build errors.