# Warnings in Angular 7 cdk drag-and-drop installing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I am developing an ionic v4 application and I need to use Angular v7 cdk drag-and-drop.

When I've launched this command in the command line:

```
npm install @angular/cdk @angular/material @angular/animations
```

I received these warnings:

```
npm WARN @ionic/pro@2.0.4 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-ionic@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/animations@7.2.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/animations@7.2.14
+ @angular/cdk@7.3.7
+ @angular/material@7.3.7
updated 3 packages and audited 53275 packages in 84.218s
```

(infact Angular cdk drag-and-drop doesen't work in my application).

This is the content of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "corsiFAD",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/video-player": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "browser": "0.2.6",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "2.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "0.9.10",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-video-player": "git+https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.14.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "com.moust.cordova.videoplayer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anoyone help me to fix these warnings, in order to use Angular cdk drag-and-drop in my app?

Comment: The output says you have installed the ```angular/cdk``` package successfully. Can you post the code that you are using where it throws the error?

Comment: Could you post your `package.json`.

Comment: @nullptr.t this is the code that doesn't work un my app:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55899157/why-angular-drag-and-drop-cdk-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment98468413_55899157

Comment: @fridoo I've edited my question with the content of my package.json

Comment: @FedeLanza Drag-and-drop not working might not have anything to do with the warnings you get, but I would still try to fix them. Update angular with `ng update` and follow the instructions. And then probably install `cordova-plugin-ionic` and `ajv`. Then run `npm i -f`.